# SQL-how to find the percentage

Tags: sql

I have a table with following values `id` and `amt`

```
id         amt      amt%
1           500     16.7
2           600     20
3           900     30
4          1000     33.3
-----------------------------
           3000     100%
```

I have to find the `amt%` for `id=1` by dividing `amt` for `id=1/sum(amt for all the ids)`.
How to write query for this in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, amt, 100.0 * amt / (select sum(amt) from tab) as amt_percent
from tab
```

Mind `100.0`, `.0` is quite important it will "force" conversion `int`s to `float`s.

**Added** after comment:

```
select t.id, t.amt, 100.0 * t.amt / p.s as amt_percent
from tab t
join (
    select id, sum(amt) as s
    from tab
    group by id
) p on p.id = t.id
```

and alternative way:

```
select id, amt, 
    100.0 * amt / (
        select sum(amt) 
        from tab t1 
        where t1.id = t.id
    ) as amt_percent
from tab t
```

I prefer joining subquery - the first one.

Comment: this query is very helpful but one more doubt actually i am grouping the table by id. in that case how to write?

Comment: @ResKing then it's going to look bit different I've added query to answer.

Comment: i am sorry for making this little more complex.. actually i am summing up all the amt for id 1 then i need to give id in group by once again. so i am getting wrong value.

Comment: @ResKing it's not clear to me. Could you edit question and add there query you are executing?

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, amt, 100*amt/(select NULLIF(sum(amt),0) from tbl) as "amt%"
from tbl
```

or maybe so

```
select t.id, t.amt, 100*amt/sm.s as "amt%"
from tbl t, (select NULLIF(sum(amt),0) as s from tbl) sm
```

**edit** check for dividing by zero

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
   id, amt, 
   amt / (SELECT SUM(amt) FROM tabl) * 100 as amtperc
FROM tabl
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Oracle (as in your previous question), try:

```
select id, amt, 100 * amt / sum(amt) over () amtperc
from your_table
```

Comment: +1 `SUM() OVER()` is more efficient than subqueries (in MS SQL Server anyway which is where my experience lies)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, amt, 100 * amt/(case when (select sum(amt)as ss from tablename)>0 then 
(select sum(amt)as ss from tablename) else 1 end) as [amt%] from tablename
```